# Excel create a group id based on string column

Tags: excel

I want excel to create column B. Basically an arbitary id for each "level of A". in `Stata` this would be `egen groupid = group(A)` or in `R` you could use `dplyr`s `group_indices()`. Whats the best way to do it in Excel? Preferably a non-VBA solution.

[image: B is what I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas for these situations are better when the first row holds unrelated column labels instead of data.

For your situation, put a 1 in B1 then this formula in B2 and drag down.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, A$1:B1, 2, FALSE),SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A$1:A2&"")))
```